# .htaccess - How to forward a domain to another except for two addresses?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following domains www.domainABC.com and www.domainABC.org

I have to forward all www.domainABC.org to www.domainABC.com except for two addresses:

```
www.domainABC.org/mylist   and
www.domainABC.org/mylist/admin
```

all other requests to the .org domain should be forward to the respective .com.

For example:

```
www.domain.org/mypage.html ... to www.domain.com/mypage.html
www.domain.org/blog/myblog?page=1 ... to www.domain.com/blog/myblog?page=1
etc.,
```

but

```
www.domainABC.org/mylist   and
www.domainABC.org/mylist/admin
```

should not be forwarded.

How do I do that using conditions on .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mylist/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mylist/admin/?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainABC.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainABC.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```